# Show a spinner until the results load from the HTTP request for autocomplete field

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to show a spinner until the results load from the HTTP request on autocomplete field. Below is the snippet of the code written.

HTML

```
 <label class="col-2 col-form-label text-right font-weight-bold">City *</label>
              <div class="col-2">
                <div>
                  <input id="typeahead-prevent-manual-entry"  type="text" class="form-control"
                         [(ngModel)]="myActivity.city"
                         [ngbTypeahead]="search"
                         [inputFormatter]="formatter"
                         [resultFormatter]="formatter"                           
                         name="citySelected"
                         #citySelected="ngModel"/>
                </div>
              <div>
```

Typescript

```
  formatter = (city: City) => city.name;
  search = (text$: Observable<string>) => text$.pipe(
    debounceTime(10),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    filter(criterion => criterion.length >= 2),
    map(criterion => criterion.length < 3 ? [] : this.searchLocalities(criterion).filter(city => new 
    RegExp(criterion, 'mi').test(city.name)).slice(0, 20))
  );

 searchLocalities(criterion: string): City[] { 
    this.isLoadingResult = true;
    this.activityService.getLocalities(this.prvCodId, criterion).subscribe(
     data => {    
    data.map(item => {
      if (this.localities.find((city) => city.name === item.name) === undefined) {
        this.localities.push(item);
      }});
    this.isLoadingResult = false;
  });
return this.localities;
```

}

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? add some loader in template based on `isLoadingResult` variable

Comment: I can't figure a way to add the spinner load to the HTML whilst the user search.

Comment: Please check this very basic working example:
https://therichpost.com/angular-9-circle-progress-bar-during-api-call/

Answer (score 1):

are you using material angular in your project? if yes you can easily use mat-proggress-spinner.

first of all import the module into your appModule:

```
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
```

add it to your imports:

```
//
imports: [MatProgressSpinnerModule]
//
```

then in your template, you can use it as bellow:

```
<div class="col-2">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoadingResult" diameter="30"></mat-spinner>
    <div *ngIf="!isLoadingResult">
    <input id="typeahead-prevent-manual-entry"  type="text" class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="myActivity.city"
        [ngbTypeahead]="search"
        [inputFormatter]="formatter"
        [resultFormatter]="formatter"                           
        name="citySelected"
        #citySelected="ngModel"/>
     </div>
<div>
```

but if you are not using material angular and you don't want to, you can just use a  tag gif instead of mat-spinner.

put the gif in your assets and:

```
<img *ngIf="isLoadingResult" src="assets/images/loading.gif" />
```

Comment: Thank you behruz. Unfortunately, I am not using angular material. However, I seem to be close to what I need here with the second option. I need the spinner inside the input tag.

Comment: The goal here is when the user type it should autocomplete the field based on the API called request. Therefore, a spinner shows until all the locations from the API are called. For now, what happens is the spinner is outside the input, therefore, it hides the whole input field, the input field shows again when the call from the API is complete.

Comment: ok so you need to set some styling.. put input and img in a container. then set to position of that container to 'relative'. set the position for img to 'absolute' and set top and left attributes.

Answer (score 1):

in your html:

```
<div class="input-container">
  <img class="loading-img" src="your loading img location">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

in your css:

```
.input-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px
}

.loading-img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 3px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

this will put the IMG in the right corner of the input.

Comment: Awesome man. I do appreciate your help. Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mat-progress-bar library, see the example below.

```js
//declaration
 isApiCalling = false;

//use case
this.isApiCalling = true;
this._apiCall.get(this.url)
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              this.isApiCalling = false;

            },
            err => {
              this.isApiCalling = false;
               }
          );
```

```html
<!-- actual term is isApiCalling -->
<mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="isApiCalling"></mat-progress-bar>
```